# Why do we say that a static method in Java is not a virtual method?

Tags: java

In object-oriented paradigm, a **virtual** function or virtual method is a function or method whose behavior can be overridden within an inheriting class by a function with the same signature to provide the **polymorphic behavior**.

---

According to the definition, every non-static method in Java is by default **virtual method** except **final and private methods**. The method which cannot be inherited for **polymorphic** behavior is **not** a virtual method.

---

***An abstract class in Java is nothing but the pure virtual method equivalent to C++.***

---

Why do we say that a static method in Java is not a virtual method? Even if we can override the static method and consequently it may give some advantages of the **polymorphism** and also a static method in Java can be invoked mostly with it's associated class name but it is also possible to invoke it using the object of it's associated class in **Java** in the same way that an instance method is invoked.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You *can't* override static methods. They are bound at compile-time. They are *not* polymorphic. Even if you try to invoke it as if it were an instance method (which IMO you shouldn't do) it's bound to the compile-time type of that expression, and the execution-time value is completely ignored (even if it's null):

```
Thread otherThread = null;
otherThread.sleep(1000); // No errors, equivalent to Thread.sleep(1000);
```

This behaviour can be very confusing for a reader, which is why at least *some* IDEs allow you to generate warnings or errors for accessing static members "through" a reference. It was a flaw in Java's design, pure and simple - but it doesn't make static methods virtual at all.

Comment: Some IDEs can flag errors or warnings if you invoke static methods in this way. I'm unsure whether there's a compiler flag that'd cause the same to be raised at compile-time, though I suspect there is.

Comment: @Romain: I don't know of anything like that for javac, I'm afraid.

Comment: Then there should be... Duh. That'd be useful to stop people from writing such misleading code.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you have class A

```
public class A
{
    public static void doAStaticThing()
    {
        System.out.println("In class A");
    }
}
```

And B

```
public class B extends A
{
    public static void doAStaticThing()
    {
        System.out.println("In class B");
    }
}
```

And a method in another class like this:

```
public void foo()
{
    B aB = new B();
    bar(B);
}

public void bar(A anA)
{
    anA.doAStaticThing(); // gives a warning in Eclipse
}
```

The message you will see on the console is

```
In class A
```

The compiler has looked at the declared type of `anA` in method bar and statically bound to class A's implementation of `doAStaticThing()`.  The method is not virtual.

Answer (score 3):

It's simple, a static method cannot be overridden by an inheriting class, since it's not inherited. So it's not virtual.

What you call "overriding a static method" is actually only defining another static method on another class. It'll only "hide" (and that's actually a much stronger word than what'd be actually true there) the other one, not override it.

Answer (score 3):

> An abstract class in Java is nothing but the pure virtual method equivalent to C++.

A class is not a method.  An abstract class doesn't have to have "virtual" or abstract methods, or even any methods.

Something C++ developers put down Java features as just like C++ renamed without understanding the differences. ;)

> Why do we say that a static method in Java is not a virtual method?

Not sure who says this, but `static` methods are not polymorphic.

> Even if we can override the static method

We can't, you can only hide or overload a static method.

Whether you use the class or sub-class or instance to invoke a static method the actual class or instance is ignored. e.g. you can do

```
((Thread) null).yield();
```

Answer (score 3):

Because polymorphism applies to objects, while a static method doesn't relate to any object (but to a class).