# static members behavior in java

Tags: java

I am confused with be below behaviour in Java, I know that static inheritance is not possible Java then how I am able to call on B class static members of A?

```
public  class A {
  static int staticVariable = 5;
  public static void staticMethod(){
  System.out.println("A");
 }
}
public class B extends A{}
public class C {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      A.staticMethod();
      B.staticMethod();
      System.out.printf("A's int value %d and B's int value is %d",A.staticVariable,B.staticVariable);
    }
}
```

output:

```
A
A
A's int value 5 and B's int value is 5
```

Comment: I think that "static inheritance" doesn't mean what you think it does. The above is perfectly legitimate Java code.

Comment: I believe it is that a static method cannot be overridden. And an base class function cannot be hidden by a static method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095457/why-do-we-say-that-a-static-method-in-java-is-not-a-virtual-method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do here is not "static inheritance" whatever that means, but plain old name resolution (at compile time). This works so that you can qualify a name with B everywhere you would put an A, except for names that are defined in B itself.

Answer (score 1):

Inheriting `static` members *is* possible, as your example shows. Polymorphic `static` functions aren't possible, so it's not possible for `B` to override `A`'s `staticMethod()`.

Comment: you are right. One can hide super class static method with subclass by using same signature. But you cannot override super class static method with subclass non static method and visa-versa by following rules of overriding.

Answer (score 1):

For class methods, the runtime system invokes the method defined in the compile-time type of the reference on which the method is called. For instance methods, the runtime system invokes the method defined in the runtime type of the reference on which the method is called.

Read this article for more details: http://krsethur.wordpress.com/2005/12/15/static-method-inheritance/

Answer (score 0):

I think static method/variable is like function in OP language.