# C++ : Calling inherited static method from static method

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Consider the following abstract class `AbstractEngine`:

```
class AbstractEngine {
    static void init();
    static std::string getName();
};
```

And consider the following 2 implementor classes:

```
class Engine1 : public AbstractEngine  {   
    static std::string getName();
};

class Engine2 : public AbstractEngine {   
    static std::string getName();
};
```

And, the `init()` function should call the correct `getName()` according to the type of class:

```
void AbstractEngine::init() {
    std::cout << getName() << std::endl;
}
```

For example, If I call `Engine1::init()`, I would like it to call `Engine1::getName()` and not `AbstractEngine::getName()`

How can I make `AbstractEngine::init()` really to call the correct implementation of `getName()`?

Comment: No way without having an actual instance of a class.

Comment: "according to the type of the instance"... But which instance, if your function is static ?

Comment: I mean if I call `Engine1::init()`, I want it to call `Engine1::getName()`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), i.e. make `AbstractEngine` a template class, then when you inherit, inherit from `AbstractEngine<EngineN>`:

```
template <typename T> 
class AbstractEngine {
public:
    static void init() {
        std::cout << T::getName() << std::endl;  
    }
};

class Engine1 : public AbstractEngine<Engine1>  {   
public:
    static std::string getName() { return "Engine1"; }
};

class Engine2 : public AbstractEngine<Engine2> {  
public:
    static std::string getName() { return "Engine2"; }
};
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/475cdae9eb6eb788)

---

If you also need some dynamic polymorphic behaviour, you can make a common non-template base class:

```
class AbstractEngine {
    //I assume you would have some virtual functions here
};

template <typename T> 
class AbstractEngineImpl : public AbstractEngine {
public:
    static void init() {
        std::cout << T::getName() << std::endl;  
    }
};

class Engine1 : public AbstractEngineImpl<Engine1>  {   
public:
    static std::string getName() { return "Engine1"; }
};

class Engine2 : public AbstractEngineImpl<Engine2> {  
public:
    static std::string getName() { return "Engine2"; }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The `getName()` method should not be static. Neither the `init()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get polymorphic behaviour, but with static functions. This doesn't make any sense. By definition, polymorphic behaviour is associated with particular instance of objects - but static functions do not have an associated instance.

If you want polymorphic behaviour (as you tag suggests), consider this redesign:

```
class AbstractEngine {
    virtual void init();
    virtual std::string getName();
};

class Engine1 : public AbstractEngine  {   
    std::string getName() override;
};

class Engine2 : public AbstractEngine {   
    std::string getName() override;
};
```

Comment: Well, this was a C++ question

Comment: Also [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095457/why-do-we-say-that-a-static-method-in-java-is-not-a-virtual-method) regarding the Java comment

Comment: I don't agree with your definition of polymorphism. There is a difference between static polymorphism (available in C++ using templates and the CRTP) and dynamic polymorphism (virtual functions, RTTI).

Comment: The exact definition of polymorphism varies according to opinion, but largely is is captured by [this](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/P/polymorphism.html) "In object-oriented programming, polymorphism refers to a programming language's ability to process objects differently depending on their data type or class. "  The key point here is "process *objects* differently". No object, no polymorphism. With static methods there is no object.

Comment: Not all polymorphism is object-oriented, and C++ isn't a pure object-oriented language.

Comment: @TartanLlama - my reply was to earlier post. Your comment: fair enough. I am indeed referring to dynamic polymorphism. I think given the context this is reasonable.

Comment: I have to admit that you're right. I was confused and too confident with myself at once.. thank you very much for the answer and to everyone who participated in the discussion